# How to find all combinations possible from alphabet and numbers

Tags: python

So basically i want it to start with for example aaaa then go to aaab and once it has done all combinations possible with 4 digits i want it to start doing 5 digits, i want this to put in a variable so it puts in aaaa when aaaa is checked it switches to aaab and so on.

Comment: This is exactly what [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) is meant to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can co-opt [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for this:

```
def my_generator(initial_length):
    while True:
        # get all permutations of length 4, in order
        for p in itertools.product('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', repeat=initial_length):
            yield ''.join(p)
        # when we run out, increase the length and start again
        initial_length += 1
```

Usage:

```
>>> x = my_generator(4)
>>> next(x)
'aaaa'
>>> next(x)
'aaab'
>>> next(x)
'aaac'
>>> [next(x) for _ in range(26**4 - 4)][-1]
'zzzy'
>>> next(x)
'zzzz'
>>> next(x)
'aaaaa'
>>> next(x)
'aaaab'
```

Comment: Can i then put it into a while/for loop please im new at this could you explain me how i could do that, anyways thanks :D

Comment: Each time you call `next(x)`, you get the next value. You can do this in a `for` or `while` loop, depending on what you want to do in that loop with this value. However, without knowing that, I can't really help you any further.